# Totally stumped! Part ID - unusual crane part?

Tags: part-identification, vintage

Is anyone able to identify this piece? I'm totally stumped in spite of searching through hundreds of vintage sets from the 60s / 70s.

[image]

Really appreciate any info, thanks!

Comment: You could try brickset, although they probably wouldn't have it since they don't have parts from the 60s and 70s. The earliest they have is the 1990s. Try going through the categories after you click on "Parts" in the "Browse" pull-down menu.

Comment: This seems to be a subpart of another assembly - likely housing some sort of electronics in the left section. You can see how the right side has the proper anti-stud tubes under the brick, but the left side looks different. This side also has the two holes (one between the left 4 studs, the other one on the sloped piece) and you can see some tabs on the inside of the brick which were likely used to mount this part of the brick onto something else (or perhaps this part was closed with a bottom lid at some point). I have looked through the BrickLink catalog but haven't yet found a match.

Comment: Thank you, I too had no luck on brickset or bricklink, but I must've been looking in the wrong places, as it is there. It reminds me of some of the unwieldy parts made around 2000, but clearly had a purpose in its time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Vehicle, Tractor Chassis Base 11 x 2 x 3](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=870&name=Vehicle,%20Tractor%20Chassis%20Base%2011%20x%202%20x%203&category=%5BVehicle%5D#T=C&C=3)